Como simplificar rotas aninhadas de comentários em Rails para evitar redundância?
Estou trabalhando em um projeto Rails onde tanto posts quanto comentários podem ter comentários aninhados, e os comentários são polimórficos.
Eu configurei as seguintes rotas:
resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :index, :create, :update]
  end
  resources :comments do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :index, :create, :update]
  end

Isso funciona para permitir que tanto posts quanto comentários tenham comentários aninhados, mas parece redundante. Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de simplificar essas rotas para evitar essa duplicação, já que as ações para comentários são as mesmas, independentemente de estarem aninhadas em um Post ou em um Comment.
Estou usando Rails 7.0.8
